# Why is this object creating without an ID value and therefore not saving it self?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm trying to learn how to develop web applications using Ruby on Rails 5, and I'm following a book (from Apress), and after a few chapters I came up with a problem.

The book teach you **RoR** creating a small and simple blog. I'm on the point on creating comments.

I have this models:
**Article**, **Comment** and **User**

Where "**Article**" has this:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

"**Comment**" has this:

```
belongs_to :article
```

And "**User**" has this:

```
has_many :articles, -> {order("published_at DESC, title ASC")},
                :dependent => :nullify

has_many :replies, :through => :articles, :source => :comments
```

And I have the *show.html.erb* view for the Article showing a *partial* for the comment creation at the end of it.

And the "**Comment**" controller has this:

```
before_action :load_article

def create
    @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to @article, notice: 'Thanks for your comment'
    else
        redirect_to @article, alert: 'Unable to add comment'
    end
end

private
    def load_article
        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body)
    end
```

The problem is that the **@comment.save** is returning false.
Also if I try to **.create** a *comment* from rails console the *comment* objet created has no **id** value, it says **nil**. And I don't know why. It worked once, but stupid me did not do a commit when it worked. Now the **comment.create()** is always returning a **nil** id comment.

So i can´t create any comments.

Does any one have any idea why is this happening?

PS: I checked and the DB schema is correct.
PS: If you need more info about it, just comment.

Comment: Most probably there is some validation error. Check what `@comment.errors` is returning. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations

Comment: @bliof, I tried what you suggested, but `@comment.errors` is empty.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX You need to check for errors after doing `@comment.save`. Or alternatively, you can call `@comment.valid?` and then `@comment.errors`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line  **@comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)**, try this:

```
def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.article = @article

     if @comment.save
         redirect_to @article, notice: 'Thanks for your comment'
     else
         redirect_to @article, alert: 'Unable to add comment'
     end
end
```

Try it, and tell us how you are doing, we will be glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this approach, but I don't have _current_user_. Cause haven't implemented _login_  and _sessions_ for users yet. That is the next section in the book, but it says that I should be able to write comments. What to do from here?

Comment: Is easy try it
@comment = comments.new(comment_params)

Comment: What? Actually I´m kinda frustrated because I think the book has typos about it, cause later in the chapter, the same line appears differently, like this: `@comment = @article.comments.new(params[:comment])` and that throws an **ForbbidenAtribute** exception. The weirdest thing is that not even from the `rails console` I am able to create a **Comment** correctly.

Comment: The best I can recommend, is to follow the official guide of Rails (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), Because as I told you, it should work. 

Comment how was it!!!